# how do pointers work when i try to make one take the value of another

Tags: c, pointers

So, let s say i have the following structure

```
typedef struct 
{
   void * value;
}Info;

typedef struct 
{
   char* title; 
   int nrOfPages;
}Book;
```

I allocate memory in main for `Book snowWhite` and then i want to call a function that will allocate an Info struct, and will make the value pointer, point to snowWhite.For this i was thinking to make:

```
((Info*)p)->value = snowWhite
```

(i declare snowWhite in main as a Book type pointer: Book* snowWhite)

Is it correct? Will this (`((Info*)p)->value = snowWhite`) make the value pointer to the memory that i have allocated to snowWhite?

Comment: Yes it will. Just write some test code and add debug print statements or use a debugger to confirm the behaviour for yourself.

Comment: Yes if you did: `Book *snowWhite = malloc(sizeof(Book));`

Comment: How is `p` declared?

Comment: What is `p`? What is the actual declaration of `snowWhite`? The one you posted contracts the question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example